# ActiveAndroid TypeSerializer with BLOB

Tags: android, serialization, activeandroid

How can I write a custom TypeSerializer for a byte[]? I have been looking around on the web, but I haven't really found anything helpfull.

```
public class ByteArraySerializer extends TypeSerializer {
@Override
public Class<?> getDeserializedType() {
    return byte[].class;
}

@Override
public SQLiteUtils.SQLiteType getSerializedType() {
    return SQLiteUtils.SQLiteType.BLOB;
}

@Override
public Object serialize(Object o) {
    return o;
}

@Override
public Object deserialize(Object o) {
    return (byte[])o;
}
}
```

I do know that my serialize and deserialize methods are implemented wrong, but I just don't know how to handle a serialization / deserialization with SQLiteType.BLOB.

Answer (score 3):

First of all in your getSerializedType() you have to return Serialized class.

Second of qall you have to serialize/deserialize your object yourself.

And you have to add your serializer to the manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="AA_SERIALIZERS" 
  android:value="my.package.CustomTypeSerializer,my.package.AnotherCustomeTypeSerializer" />
```